# Multidimensional version of mean value theorem?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f=(f_1, \ldots, f_m): U\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ be a differentiable function on an open subset $U\subset \mathbb R^n$. Let $x, y\in U$ such that

$$[x, y]=\{\lambda\cdot x+(1-\lambda)\cdot y: \lambda\in [0, 1]\}\subset U.$$

I'd like to show there are points $p_1, \ldots, p_m\in [x, y]\setminus\{x, y\}$ such that

$$f(y)-f(x)=(df_1(p_1)(y-x), \ldots, df_m(p_m)(y-x)).$$

**Attempt.** For each $j\in \{1, \ldots, m\}$ we may define

$$g_j: [0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$

setting

$$g_j(t)=f_j((1-t)\cdot x+t\cdot y)).$$
Notice $g_j$ is well defined, since $(1-t)\cdot x+t\cdot y\in [x, y]\subset U$ for every $t\in [0, 1]$. Furtheremore, $g_j$ is continuous in $[0, 1]$ and differentiable in $(0, 1)$. By the mean value theorem there is $t_j\in (0, 1)$ such that

$$g_j(1)-g_j(0)=g_i^\prime(t_j)(1-0)=g_j^\prime(0).$$
But this is equivalent to

$$f_j(y)-f_j(x)=df_j((1-t_j)\cdot x+t_j\cdot y))(y-x).$$
Setting $p_j=(1-t_j)\cdot x+t_j\cdot y\in [x, y]\setminus\{x, y\}$ it follows

\begin{align*}
f(y)-f(x)&=(f_1(y)-f_1(x), \ldots, f_m(y)-f_n(x))\\
&=(df_1(p_1)(y-x), \ldots, df_m(p_m)(y-x)).
\end{align*}

Is my proof correct? Further, it is not necessary to require $f$ to be $C^1$, right?

Comment: What is $df_i$ ?

Comment: Why different $t_j$ ? There is one $t\in [0,1]$  which fits for all equations and one point $p \in [x,y] $ s.t. $f(y)-f(x)= \nabla f (p) (y-x)$

Comment: @CircleLover it is the differential $df_i: \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ of the component $f_i: U\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Maksim Notice that $f$ takes its values in $\mathbb R^m$, so $f(y)-f(x)\in\mathbb R^m$ whereas $\nabla f$ is not defined, unless you set $\nabla f(p)=(\nabla f_1(p), \ldots, \nabla f_m(p))$.

Comment: Mh, what I suspected. Does it make sense to have a finite difference in one member and differentials in the other ?

Comment: Why not? Notice that $df_j(p_j)(y-x)\in \mathbb R$ for every $j$.

Comment: @Maksim In the end of the day, it seems it is just the mean value theorem applied to the components of $f$. But we don't have a point $p$ which will hold for all the components, since they are different functions.

Comment: In the old conceptualization, a differential is an infinitesimal. In the modern world, it is a linear application. The equation does not make sense.

Comment: @Circle Lover I still don't see where the problem is. Why the equation does not make sense? It is simply the multivariable mean value theorem applied to the component functions $f_j: U\subset \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Comment: Missed that the the range is $\mathbb{R}^m$, apologies.

Comment: Yeah, it's alright. Maybe you only need existence of all directional derivatives of $f$ everywhere.

Comment: Just in case you don't already know, you can take all $p_i$ to be equal if you accept an inequality of norms instead.

Comment: @Maksim No problem.

Comment: @LázaroAlbuquerque Yep, I'm aware. But this time I need equality. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the meaning of $dy=1$ ?

Comment: You tell me, it is your notation, you have to make it clear. Without any further information it is hard to say anything about it.

Comment: Probably you're identifying the differential of the function $f(y)=y$ with $f^\prime(1)$, due to the general fact that $df(x)=f^\prime(1)\cdot x$ for real funcions of real variables.